# Change plotBand label after creation [highcharts]

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart where the plotBands resize, and the labels have to change. However I cannot figure out how to change the labels after the chart is created.

I have tried:

changing the chart.axis[0].options.plotBands[0].label.text, marking the axis as isDirty and redrawing the chart

using an HTML label and changing the value via jQuery

Do I have to use a label formatter function or is there something in the API I missed?

Comment: I was able to do this by directly modifying the tspan.text() using jQuery. It would be nice to do this in the Highcharts API however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use attr() function which allows to update graph elements like plotBand label. Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/eaFdr/1/

```
 $('#btn').click(function(){
        chart.xAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[0].label.attr({
                    text:'aaaa'
                });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to change the "to/from" values of the plotbands and found no attr method, this worked though:

```
    this.chart.yAxis[0].plotLinesAndBands[4].options.from = this.min;
```